# What other options are there available to position several checkboxes in an orderly manner except for the HTML table element?

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I was wondering if the HTML table element is still up to date for positioning several checkbox input fields in an orderly manner, or if there are more up to date options available, for example with css or other html elements?

Here my example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="grade1">Grade 1</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grade1" id="grade1" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="grade2">Grade 2</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grade2" id="grade2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="grade3">Grade 3</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grade3" id="grade3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="grade4">Grade 4</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grade4" id="grade4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="grade5">Grade 5</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grade5" id="grade5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="grade6">Grade 6</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grade6" id="grade6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="grade8">High school</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grade8" id="grade8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use css grid to achieve a similar layout.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <label for="grade1">Grade 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grade1" id="grade1" checked>
  <label for="grade2">Grade 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grade2" id="grade2">
  <label for="grade3">Grade 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grade3" id="grade3">
  <label for="grade4">Grade 4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grade4" id="grade4">
  <label for="grade5">Grade 5</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grade5" id="grade5">
  <label for="grade6">Grade 6</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grade6" id="grade6">
  <label for="grade8">High school</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grade8" id="grade8">
</div>
```